# Using EXIF and BinaryFile get an error

Tags: javascript, filereader, exif

I'm trying to  draw photo with correct orientation in canvas after capture photo by using `input[type='file']` in mobile web browser for that I'm using:

```
fileReader.onloadend = function() {
    var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));

    switch(exif.Orientation){
       case 8:
           ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
           break;
       case 3:
           ctx.rotate(180*Math.PI/180);
           break;
       case 6:
           ctx.rotate(-90*Math.PI/180);
           break;
    }
};
```

But I get: `TypeError: First argument to DataView constructor must be an ArrayBuffer`?

How can I get this array buffer?

I'm using EXIF.js and BinaryFile.js

Comment: can you show us the whole `FileReader` code?

Comment: Please link the libraries you're using explicitly. There are so many exif libraries, all of them called exif.js!

Answer (score 12):

You need to convert the base64 string to an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) for ExifJs:

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer (base64) {
    base64 = base64.replace(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/gmi, '');
    var binaryString = atob(base64);
    var len = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

You don't need `BinaryFile`:

```
var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(this.result));
```

This assumes you are using `FileReader` with `readAsDataURL` to get `this.result`.

**A better approach** would be to read the file as an array buffer to begin with and not convert it to base64 and then back again using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(). Something along the lines of this (pseudocode):

```
// `file` = files[0] from input change event
function getFileArrayBuffer(file) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      resolve(new Uint8Array(reader.result));
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi , i got such error "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."

as i 'm using reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

Comment: @Dominic - can you use FileReader with readAsArrayBuffer for this.result and use that directly in EXIF.readFromBinaryFile?

Comment: @NealDavis not sure but sounds likely, if you can then that sounds like the best answer :)

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Np, I also just added some pseudo code on an approach that I think would be more efficient. Might need some tweaking but essentially I think it should be possible to not have to convert to base64 first

Answer (score -1):

@chings228 you must pass base64 data to base64ToArrayBuffer, not blob data.

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer (base64) {
    base64 = base64.replace(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/gmi, '');
    var binaryString = atob(base64);
    var len = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}

var b64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+$parameters.image;
var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(b64));
alert(exif.Orientation);
```

Comment: Consider other format when answering commenters question as right now it  takes quite some time to realise what your anwser brings to the table except being duplicate of [@Dominic Tobias](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32592930/2947756)